# Use Selenium Driver to load page, dismiss/dispose it and keep browser active

Tags: vb.net, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver to load a specific feature from an application, a rich text editor (actually a custom release of [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)) and the code below works perfectly for that... *except* that I would like to release Selenium objects (and geckodriver.exe/marionnette black cmd window) since the desired page was loaded. But either `.Close()`, `.Quit()` or `.Dispose()` methods will wipe out the Firefox window as well...

Is there a way to dismiss Selenium Webdriver and keep Firefox running by its own?

Thank you very much

```
Private Sub LoadResource()
    Dim FFD As New OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver()

    'Set timeout of 60 seconds for steps to complete successfully 
    Dim WDW As New OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(FFD, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))

    'navigate to login page
    FFD.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://www.myapplication.com/login")

    'Wait until application loads main page (this means login was successful)
    WDW.Until(Function() FFD.Url = "https://www.myapplication.com/")

    'Load built-in rich text editor Rich text
    FFD.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://www.myapplication.com/editor?document=1080199")

    'Wait for successful loading of the editor page
    WDW.Until(Function() FFD.Url = "https://www.myapplication.com/editor?document=1080199")

     'That's all. 
     'here I'd like to release Firefox to keep running and get rid  of WebDriver's objects and resources, if possible.

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried killing geckodriver? After that you can call driver.Quit(), catch all exceptions (about the lost connection to geckodriver and so on) and your Firefox instance will still be alive

Comment: @Kirhgoph, no, I didn't try that, but if it is the only way, I shall do that. Thanks!

Comment: I would manually close geckodriver's windows and see if it closes Firefox too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on [Kirhgoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7710443/kirhgoph)'s comment and seems to work well:

```
Private Sub LoadResource()
    Dim FFD As New OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver()
    Dim GDP As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("geckodriver").Last
    Dim WDW As New OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(FFD, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
    FFD.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://www.myapplication.com/login")
    WDW.Until(Function() FFD.Url = "https://www.myapplication.com/")
    FFD.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://my.application.com/editor?document=1080199")
    WDW.Until(Function() FFD.Url = "https://www.myapplication.com/editor?document=1080199")
    GDP.CloseMainWindow()
    GDP.WaitForExit()
    FFD.Quit()
End Sub
```